# Referencing variable length relation path in where clause

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have query with variable length path. Is it possible to use relation in `where` for filtering paths (without using `with`), for example like this:

```
match (u:user{id:1})-[r*1..2]->(n) where u-[r[0]]-(:event) return n
```

This will work but will be slower:

```
match (u:user{id:1})-[r*1..2]->(n) with u, r[0] as r0, n where u-[r0]-(:event) return n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

This should return the same result, but without a WITH clause:

```
MATCH (u:user{id:1})-[]->(e:event)
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[]->(x)
RETURN coalesce(x, e) as n;
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I'm asking exactly what I'm asking. No need to optimize my queries ;-)

Comment: So, does my answer's second query answer your question? It has no `WITH` clause, but should do the same work.

Comment: No. And your query will give different result.

Comment: @rsk: Please see my corrected my answer. I believe it now answers your question.